# Executing batch file from Informatica

Tags: batch-file, informatica, informatica-cloud

I am pulling a file from an API via Informatica, but it is in a format that isn't usable. To correct this I have a batch file that removes the characters I can't use. I have tested this process locally with a subset of data and it works. However, when I move to an Informatica process the run time balloons. Locally it runs in about 2 minutes, while it takes 4 hours when using Informatica. I use the batch file three times:

`batchsubstitute.bat "]," "" temp_racial_census_tract1.txt>exp1.txt`

`batchsubstitute.bat "]" "" exp1.txt>exp2.txt`

`batchsubstitute.bat "[," "" exp2.txt>exp3.txt`

When I look at the log I am seeing the first use taking the expected 2 minutes, and then the other two taking hours. Am I using the batch file wrong? I appreciate any insight.

Comment: Without seeing the contents of `batchsubstitute.bat`, it's not possible to answer your question. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76055032/edit) to include the contents of the script, since this isn't a script that anybody besides you has.

Comment: It would be useful to see the logs.